# In pyspark, how do you draw histogram from groupedby data?

Tags: pyspark, group-by, histogram

I have a dataframe that looks like the following,

```
+-------+--------+
|Charges|  Status|
+-------+--------+
|  495.6|  Denied|
|1806.28|  Denied|
|  261.3|Accepted|
| 8076.5|Accepted|
|1041.24|  Denied|
| 507.88|  Denied|
|  208.0|Accepted|
| 152.49|  Denied|
|  146.0|Accepted|
|2794.14|Accepted|
+-------+--------+
```

How do I get two histograms based on groupBy('Status), using the databricks' display() function? Thank you.